# Restrict duplication of Alias name while creating a distribution list using Exchange commands

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, distribution-lists

I am trying to create a new distribution list using exchange server commands given in [Creating new distribution list command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998856(v=exchg.160).aspx).

When I enter a duplicate alias name it is allows me to create the new distribution list.

While when I try to create the distribution list from the Exchange Server UI in Office 365 then it gives me an error if I enter the duplicate Alias name.

I want to know how I can achieve the same functionality using commands also.

**Update**

I am using following command

```
New-DistributionGroup Name 'Distribution-List-Name' Alias 'Alias-Name' ErrorAction 'Stop'
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean duplicate alias name? Do you mean you try to create a DL with an alias that already exists? Do you mean that you try to add a secondary alias to a DL?

Comment: Please provide the command you are running in PowerShell.

Comment: Updated the question with Command

Answer (score 0):

Aakash Morya,

Have you tried this syntax?

```
New-DistributionGroup -Name <DL name> -DisplayName <DL display name> -Alias <Alias> -PrimarySmtpAddress <Email Address>
```

http://o365info.com/manage-distribution-groups-by-using/#SUB-1

To do this from Office 365, you go to Exchange Administration and go to Recipients, Click the Groups, Click the plus sign, Click Distribution group, Enter a Display name, Enter an Alias, Enter a Name, Select the owner, Select the members, Click Save.

http://office365support.ca/creating-a-distribution-group-exchange-online/